# Norms of vectors in a equilateral triangle

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

Given the equilateral triangle $ABC$, I know $A(0,0,0)$ and I'm trying to find the coordinates of $B$ and $D$.

I know
$$AB\cdot AC=8$$
and the normalized vectors associated to them are
$$AB_0=(1,0,0)$$
and
$$AC_0=\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},0\right)$$

What I did was: since $ABC$ is equilateral, then
$$||AB||=||AC||$$
so
$$||AB\cdot AC||=||8||\Rightarrow||AB||\cdot||AC||=8$$
Therefore, their norms are both equal to $\sqrt{8}$.

Hence, there are real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that the vectors
$$\alpha(1,0,0),\qquad\beta\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},0\right)$$
have norms $\sqrt{8}$, which clearly gives me
$$\alpha=\beta=\sqrt{8}$$

But when I try to do the dot product between
$$(\sqrt{8},0,0)$$
and
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{8}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{8}\cdot\sqrt{3}}{2},0\right)$$
I get 4 as result. What is wrong?

Comment: $\vec{AB}\cdot \vec{AC}=|AB|\cdot |AC|\cdot \cos 60^\circ$